# NSOpenPanel setCanChooseFiles does not work for objective-C. Is this an Apple bug?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Here is the code

```
NSOpenPanel *anOpenPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[anOpenPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[anOpenPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[anOpenPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
NSInteger aReturnCode = [anOpenPanel runModal];
```

This will open up the view, BUT a user can still select files by doubleclicking it. Is this an Apple bug?

**[EDIT]**

This code will open up the panel box correctly. You will also see the files grayed out as it should be. However, **Double Clicking** a grayed out file will still close the box even though it is an invalid selection. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: You have `setCanChooseFiles:YES` and say "BUT a user can still select files by doubleclicking". It looks like you have not written what you intended... but what did you intend? (Suggest you edit the question.)

Comment: My mistake, I have edited the question.

Comment: This is known to work... What version of Xcode & OS X are you using? Are you sandboxed? Any more context you can give for the code fragment that might present a clue to someone?

Comment: Im using Xcode 6.4 (latest) OS Yosimite (latest i think). The problem is that, double clicking a file, still closes the panel even though `setCanChooseFiles` is set to no. Just create a new blank XCode project yourself and paste the code lines above into a simple NSButton. You will see it happening on your machine your self.

Comment: Your code fragment works fine on 10.10.4 with Xcode 6.4, both in and out of the sandbox - just run as the body of `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` - can't get much more barebones than that. `NSOpenPanel` has had a chequered history under the sandbox, but that should be in the past by now. All files are grayed out an cannot be double-clicked. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Can i ask you one last question. You are correct when you said the files are grayed out. But have you tried double clicking the grayed out files? On double clicking the grayed out files, the box still closes. Shouldnt the box stay open since files should not be selected? I thought the double click event for files should be disabled. Question updated

Comment: see previous comment, the files are greyed out and cannot be double clicked to close the box. Your problem is elsewhere.